# On-demand creation of a container in an existing kubernetes pod

Tags: node.js, typescript, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Assume that I have a pod active and contains only one active container initially.
This container is a nodejs application in typescript and shows user interface when opened in browser.

Can this container create another container on-demand/dynamically within the SAME POD ?
How can we achieve this? Please advise.

Also, will reusing npm modules like https://www.npmjs.com/package/kubernetes-client help in creating such containers within the same pod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this container create another container on-demand/dynamically within the SAME POD ? How can we achieve this?

No, the containers within a Pod is declared in the `PodTemplate` that need to be declared upfront before the pod is created. More specific, what use case do you have? What are you trying to achieve?

> Also, will reusing npm modules like https://www.npmjs.com/package/kubernetes-client help in creating such containers within the same pod?

A kubernetes client library is useful for interacting with the ApiServer, e.g. for deploying new applications or Pods. But the Kubernetes *deployment unit* is a **Pod** - that is the smallest unit you work with. To change a Pod, you create a new one and terminated the previous one.